# Android DrawerLayout with sub views/fragements

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have added a Drawer Layout to my activity to be used for filtering (based on the eBay app filtering).

[image: Drawer Initial layout]

My issue is I can't work out how to click on "Features" which will then display a new view (appearing/transitioning from right to left) that allows me to filter the "Features".

[image: Displayed when clicking on "Features]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, you can add a `fragment`, with your default content, on a layout component (can be a `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`/etc).
When you click on a menu item of your drawer, you will replace your `fragment` (another content).

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationView`.

Find a good tutorial or use [this one](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/material-navigation-drawer-with-navigationview/):

You can see it's easy to handle click events, just do your thing instead of just closing the drawer.

I'd just suggest to use `FrameLayout` instead of LinearLayout in `activity_main.xml` for the container of your main content.

Here's also a series of videos about this:
[slidenerd's channel](http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/)